# Where to give index.php properly?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, php-cli

I have `/var/www/html/moodle` as my website directory. When in `mysite.conf` the settings are as follows:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DirectoryIndex "index.php"
```

mysite.com gives an `Index of/` page since there is only apache's `index.html` in the default location as index file.
How can I make mysite.com load `/var/www/html/moodle/index.php`?

I tried giving in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`

```
DirectoryIndex "/moodle/index.php"
```

With this mysite.com loads the moodle homepage, but other`index` pages inside moodle are not loading.

How to solve this?

**Update (Solution)**

I had to make a change in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf` as

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /moodle/index.php
```

Comment: Either update your DocumentRoot, to point at the moodle directory, or add a redirect at the root root to redirect everything to /moodle/

Comment: Tried updating DocumentRoot in the .conf file from apache2/sites-available. It didn't work. How to add redirect at the root root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your site is /var/www/html and entering your URL in your browser as the root, for example http://example.com will display the root contents. http://example.com/moodle should display your index.php if it exists.

I'm an Nginx kind of guy and am not an expert on Apache but I believe this "[mod_dir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html)" is important. Make certain it has been enabled through one of the included module files. Chances are it is enabled by default.

The link for mod_dir (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html contains some good examples.

If you want you http root to load from moodle then move the root to /var/www/html/moodle or move the moodle files to the root.

After making changes to the Apache config you should reload the Apache service, I think it's called httpd or similar.

Comment: I changed `DirectoryIndex index.php /moodle/index.php` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf` file. It works now, thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working. :)